# How should I calculate the disjoint elements of 2 sets?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Given are two (either ordered or not ordered) sets A and B of elements of the same type, where an arbitrary number of elements exists in A, B or both.

I would like to determine which elements in A are not contained in B as well as which elements of B are not contained in A.

This can easily be done via

```
var dA = A.Except(B);
var dB = B.Except(A);
```

My question: Is this the most efficient algorithm for this task?

Since the above iterates both sets, it appears we might be able to re-use some information from the first iteration to reduce the effort spent on the second.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? Output it? Determine the cardinalities?

Comment: You could use the fact that the XOR is the negation of the intersection: Remove all elements which exist in both sets.

Comment: Hi @Niklas, I'm using the (entire) `dA` and `dB` sets in further computations - the details are probably not important.

Comment: @Niklas Isn't the Except method already O(n*log(n))?

Comment: @mafu Nevermind. Ignore my comment and check my answer ;)

Comment: @delnan I'm afraid that removing the elements might be more computationally intensive than the naive method? But it depends on the data structure used for the sets, I suppose.

Comment: @Servy Oh, because it is ordered. Indeed.

Comment: @mafu All of the bounds here depend on the exact data structure, but all decent set data structures I'm aware of have the same time bounds for insertion and deletion. Constant factors may differ, but rarely significantly.

Comment: I will update the question with more information, and make it broader to be more useful

Comment: @mafu It being ordered is irrelivant.  It will be O(n) on unordered data.  Being ordered in no way improves the efficiency of that operation.

Comment: Haven't actually benchmark it, but it may be worth looking into [HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). OTOH, if you actually need to keep track from which set the resulting elements came, what you already do with `Except` is probably the best you can do.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, why only O(n)?

Comment: @mafu Because it takes O(1) time to check one item, and there are n items to check, which results in O(n) time.

Comment: @Servy Oh. That was easy :)

Answer (score 2):

Let `n` be the size of set `A` and `m` be the size of set `B`. If we assume that `A` and `B` are implemented as hash tables, there's a simple `O(min(n,m))` expected time algorithm to find `A \ B` and `B \ A`.

W.l.o.g let `n < m` (otherwise swap the sets).

1. Iterate through `A`. For every element, check whether it is in `B` as well. If yes, remove it from `B`. If no, add it to `dA`.
2. I thought there would be a second step but in fact you're done already.

The result will be in `dA` and `B`.

If you don't want to destroy `B`, you can create a copy of it beforehand, which should be very fast when implemented as a simple `memcpy`.

You *could* instead use a [persistent data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) to represent `B`, but this adds a considerable cost and is unlikely to be helpful, unless your set sizes are *very* unbalanced.

Comment: I added the option for the sets to be not ordered, but this answer probably applies to the new case as well?

Comment: @mafu: I assume expected `O(1)` lookup, insertion and deletion, which you can achieve with hash tables. The problem is that you destroy the hash table for `B` in the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you can iterate sets in order, then it is possible to use algorithm like merge-phase of mergesort:

```
a = A.First
b = B.First
while a <> Nil and b <> Nil do
if a < b
  dA.Add(a)
  a = A.Next 
else if a > b
   dB.Add(b)
   b = B.Next 
else
   a = A.Next 
   b = B.Next 
endwhile
if a <> Nil
   dA.Add(rest of A)
if b <> Nil
   dB.Add(rest of B)
```

Comment: @Niklas B.  Yes, but this method gets rid of double work. I see that question is edited with unordered sets, so my answer now covers only special case

Comment: How does it get rid of double work? It also iterates through both sets completely

Comment: I suggest that for ordered sets A.Except(B) iterates through both sets and B.Except(A) iterates them again (probably O(NlogM+MlogN))

Comment: That's not true though. `A.Except(B)` iterates through `A` and `B.Except(A)` iterates through `B`. Although if you don't use hashing, you have an additional logarithmic factor, which you avoid by using the approach you propose :)